# How To run LINQ queries with Type of <T>

Tags: c#, linq

This is My Class which is basically Closed Coupled To Type  I want to Generalise this Class.

So I can use with all the Class

one thing is common that there will be a Name field while invoking this method

```
    public class CustomSuggestionProvider : ISuggestionProvider
    {
        private const int batchSize = 30;
        private string _criteria = string.Empty;
        private int _skipCount;

        private readonly ObservableCollection<LanguageItem> _observableCollection;
        private readonly List<LanguageItem> _source;

        public CustomSuggestionProvider(ObservableCollection<LanguageItem> observableCollection, List<LanguageItem> source)
        {
            _observableCollection = observableCollection;
            _source = source;
        }

        public bool HasMoreSuggestions { get; private set; } = true;

        public Task<IList<object>> GetSuggestionsAsync(string criteria, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _criteria = criteria;
            var newItems = _source.Where(x => x.Name.IndexOf(_criteria, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0).ToList();
            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                return null;
            HasMoreSuggestions = newItems.Count > batchSize;
            _skipCount = batchSize;
            return Task.FromResult<IList<object>>(newItems.Take(batchSize).Cast<object>().ToList());
        }

     
    }
```

I Just made it Generalised like this.

Made all the closely coupled class to Type T.

Kindly have a look.

```
 public class CustomSuggestionProvider<T> :  ISuggestionProvider
    {
        private const int batchSize = 30;
        private string _criteria = string.Empty;
        private int _skipCount;
        
        private readonly ObservableCollection<T> _observableCollection;
        private readonly List<T> _source;

        public CustomSuggestionProvider(ObservableCollection<T> observableCollection, List<T> source)
        {
            _observableCollection = observableCollection;
            _source = source;
        }
 

        public bool HasMoreSuggestions { get; private set; } = true;
]


        public Task<IList<object>> GetSuggestionsAsync(string criteria, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _criteria = criteria;
                var newItems = _source.Where(x =>Name.IndexOf(_criteria, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0).ToList();
            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                return null;
            HasMoreSuggestions = newItems.Count > batchSize;
            _skipCount = batchSize;
            return Task.FromResult<IList<object>>(newItems.Take(batchSize).Cast<object>().ToList());
        }

        public Task<IList<object>> GetSuggestionsAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var newItems = _source.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(_criteria)).Skip(_skipCount).ToList();
            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                return null;
            HasMoreSuggestions = newItems.Count > batchSize;
            _skipCount += batchSize;
            return Task.FromResult<IList<object>>(newItems.Take(batchSize).Where(x => !_observableCollection.Any(y => y.Id == x.Id)).Cast<object>().ToList());
        }
    }
```

I just stuck when at this statement

The 'Name' does not exist here

```
var newItems = _source.Where(x => x.Name.IndexOf(_criteria, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0).ToList();
```

Can you please help troubleshoot this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you give some more information about the variable `_source`? What type is it?

Comment: You are not passing start index to use IndexOf method

Comment: That is correct. If you want to access `T.Name`, you need to [limit the `T`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) to something that always has a `Name`.

Comment: By default T is type of `object` and `object` don't have the property `Name`. You need constraint the generic type : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters

Comment: Source is of type T.          private readonly List<T> _source;
StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase is Emum so am passing it

Comment: Modified request all of you to have a look

Answer (score 2):

You sould to write an interface like this

```cs
public interface IName
{
    string Name { set; get; }
}
```

note : all you'r classes should implement from IName

write  function like this

```cs
public static IList<IName> Names(IList<IName> names, string _criteria)
{
    return names.Where(c => c.Name.IndexOf(_criteria, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0).ToList();
}
```

and this for IEnumerable as extension method

```cs
public static class IEnumerableExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<IName> Filter(this IEnumerable<IName> names, string _criteria)
    {
        return names.Where(c => c.Name.IndexOf(_criteria, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You has two options.
First - object must inherit interface/class that contains Name property. Second you can use reflection and access the Name property with compiled lambda

```
    List<ObjectWithName> items = new List<ObjectWithName>()
    {
        new ObjectWithName { Name = "Hello World #1"},
        new ObjectWithName { Name = "Hello World #2"}
    };

    var result = FirstOption(items, "Hello");
    result = SecondOption(items, "Hello");
    ...

    public static List<T> FirstOption<T>(IList<T> source, string criteria) where T: IObjectWithName
    {
        return source.Where(t => t.Name.IndexOf(criteria, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0).ToList();
    }

    public static List<T> SecondOption<T>(IList<T> source, string criteria)
    {
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty("Name");
        MethodInfo getterMethodInfo = propertyInfo.GetGetMethod();
        ParameterExpression entity = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        MethodCallExpression getterCall = Expression.Call(entity, getterMethodInfo);
        UnaryExpression castToObject = Expression.Convert(getterCall, typeof(string));
        LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(castToObject, entity);
        var functionThatGetsValue = (Func<T, string>)lambda.Compile();

        return source.Where(t => functionThatGetsValue(t).IndexOf(criteria, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0).ToList();
    }
}

public class ObjectWithName: IObjectWithName
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IObjectWithName
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

For optimization you can compile lambda only once for type and cache results

Comment: I am trying the second option but stuck at the return statement,  functionThatGetsValue(t) . What is 't' here. @dmitry-kolchev

Comment: @RaviV t is an element of source that has type T. functionThatGetValue is compiled lambda that equivalent to string GetName<T>(T t) => (string)typeof(T).GetProperty("Name").GetValue(t); and that function returns Name property of t

Comment: I just modified the question can you have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Nicer (in my opinion) than either the 'require an `IName` interface' or 'use reflection' options is this: when constructing a `CustomSuggestionProvider<T>`, pass in a `Func<T, string>` which the provider can invoke whenever it needs a `T`'s name.

Add in `CustomSuggestionProvider<T>`

```
Func<T, string> nameGetter;
```

Initialise it in the constructor, with callers passing in something like `class => class.Name`.

Then whenever you need a `T`'s name, you just invoke this function. So your

```
var newItems = _source
    .Where(x => x.Name.IndexOf(_criteria, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
    .ToList();
```

becomes

```
var newItems = _source
    .Where(x => nameGetter(x).IndexOf(_criteria, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
    .ToList();
```